# How do I get rid of the numbers at the bottom of the boxplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvY2h.png)

```
ggplot(mtc, aes(cyl, disp))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

Above is a image of boxplots using the data from mtcars in R, and my original code. How do I get rid of the numbers at the bottom of the graph, as I already have the cylinder numbers at the top?

Changing the axis.text and axis.title using theme() didn't help. It just stretched/shrunk the plot by a tiny amount.

Comment: parharps you are looking for `ggplot(mtc, aes(factor(cyl), disp, group = cyl)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks, that was what I was looking for. But now the x-label is 'factor(cyl)'. Is there a way to not have it be like that other than using `xlab("cyl")?` Just asking in case there's a practical use for when I need to use `factor(dataname)` on the y-axis one day

Comment: `ggplot(mutate(mtc, cyl = factor(cyl)), aes(cyl, disp, group = cyl)) + geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `group` instead of `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(mutate(mtc, cyl = factor(cyl)), aes(cyl, disp, group = cyl)) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

---

On using `facet_wrap` try:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=disp))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~factor(cyl))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL)+
  xlab('cyl')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use element_blank() function, which is in ggplot2, trying adding to the theme function.

```
ggplot(mtc, aes(cyl, disp))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```